# Creating a google form/quiz from a google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a multiple choice question form to be created from data in a google spreadsheet. I managed to create the form of 60 questions each with 4 choices and setting the correct choice based on the information I have in the spreadsheet.

Last thing I need to do is to insert the correct feedback for each question based on column G in my spreadsheet that contains the feedback for each question.

Edit: here is a picture of how my spreadsheet & form would look like

[Picture for Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kento.png)

[Picture for how the form questions should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fEYS.png)

[Picture of how the form questions look like (without a feedback)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6uL1.png)

The problem is that is not being implemented, The maximum I could was to set a fixed feedback/word for all questions, but was not possible to import the specific feedback for each question to the feedback section of each question, could anyone help with that, below is my code:

```
function popForm() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var numberRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var myQuestions = sheet.getRange(1,1,numberRows,1).getValues();
  var myAnswers = sheet.getRange(1,2,numberRows,1).getValues();
  var myGuesses = sheet.getRange(1,2,numberRows,4).getValues();
  var myfeedback = sheet.getRange(1,7,numberRows,1).getValues();
  var myShuffled = myGuesses.map(shuffleEachRow);
  Logger.log(myShuffled);
  Logger.log(myAnswers);
  // Create the form as a quiz.  The resulting form's "Quiz options" are different from a manually created quiz.  Be aware (and change manually if needed!
  var form = FormApp.create('Fast Track Question - Domain I');
  form.setIsQuiz(true);
  // Write out each multiple choice question to the form.
  for(var i=0;i<numberRows;i++){
    if (myShuffled[i][0] == myAnswers[i][0]) {
      var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
      addItem.setTitle(myQuestions[i][0])
      .setPoints(1)
      .setChoices([
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][0],true),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][1]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][2]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][3])
      ]);
      var incorrectFeedback = FormApp.createFeedback()
      .setText(myfeedback[i][7])
      .build();
      addItem.setFeedbackForIncorrect(incorrectFeedback);
    }
    else if (myShuffled[i][1] == myAnswers[i][0]) {
      var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
      addItem.setTitle(myQuestions[i][0])
      .setPoints(1)
      .setChoices([
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][0]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][1],true),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][2]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][3])
      ]);
      var incorrectFeedback = FormApp.createFeedback()
      .setText(myfeedback[i][7])
      .build();
      addItem.setFeedbackForIncorrect(incorrectFeedback);
    }
    else if (myShuffled[i][2] == myAnswers[i][0]) {
      var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
      addItem.setTitle(myQuestions[i][0])
      .setPoints(1)
      .setChoices([
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][0]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][1]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][2],true),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][3])
      ]);
      var incorrectFeedback = FormApp.createFeedback()
      .setText(myfeedback[i][7])
      .build();
      addItem.setFeedbackForIncorrect(incorrectFeedback);
    }
    else if (myShuffled[i][3] == myAnswers[i][0]) {
      var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
      addItem.setTitle(myQuestions[i][0])
      .setPoints(1)
      .setChoices([
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][0]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][1]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][2]),
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][3],true)
      ]);
      var incorrectFeedback = FormApp.createFeedback()
      .setText(myfeedback[i][7])
      .build();
      addItem.setFeedbackForIncorrect(incorrectFeedback);
    }
  }
}


// This function, called by popForm, shuffles the 5 choices.
function shuffleEachRow(array) {
  var i, j, temp;
  for (i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can send your responses to Properties Service and have them sent by the onFormSubject trigger in the spreadsheet.  You will have to figure out how to identify each response so that it is sent to the correct respondent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Proposed change to script

Your code was long and I found it easier to re-write it with a few extra tools such as `getDataRange`, `push` and `splice` and `forEach`.

It seemed you were calling the methods in the right way, but since you were having to repeat yourself in a few places and keep track of many arrays and indices, it is likely that a small mistake came up.

This is a working script adapted from yours:

```js
function createQuiz() {
  let file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet = file.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  
  // Instead of getting individual ranges, it is more efficient
  // to get all the data in one go, and then operate on the two
  // dimensional array in memory.
  let range = sheet.getDataRange();
  let values = range.getValues();

  // Here I am using a existing form to test, but you can just
  // create a new one if you want.
  var form = FormApp.openById("[TESTING_ID]");
  
  
  form.setIsQuiz(true);

  values.shift(); // Using this to remove the first row of headers

  // Going through each line using a forEach to create a
  // multiple choice question
  values.forEach(q => {
    let choices = [q[1], q[2], q[3], q[4]];
    let title = q[0];
    let feedback = q[5]

    // Calling function to create multiple choice question
    createShuffledChoices(form, title, choices, feedback)
  });
}


function createShuffledChoices(form, title, choices, feedback){

  let item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();

  item.setTitle(title)
  .setPoints(1)

  // Setting up the array that will be passed into item.setChoices()
  let shuffledChoices = [];
  // Making sure that the correct answer is only marked once
  let correctAnswerChosen = false;

  // I found I had to shuffle the questions within the process of
  // creating choices as it made it easier to maintain the spreadsheet
  for (let i = choices.length; i != 0; i--) {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i - 1));
    // If the first answer is chosen, it is the correct one.
    if (rand == 0 && correctAnswerChosen == false) {
      // Combination of push and splice to remove from ordered array
      // to the shuffled one
      shuffledChoices.push(item.createChoice(choices.splice(rand, 1)[0], true));
      // Marking the correct answer as chosen,
      // so that no others are marked correct.
      correctAnswerChosen = true;
    } else {
      shuffledChoices.push(item.createChoice(choices.splice(rand, 1)[0]));
    }  
  }
  
  // Finally setting the choices.
  item.setChoices(shuffledChoices);

  // Creating the feedback
  let formFeedback = FormApp.createFeedback().setText(feedback).build();
  item.setFeedbackForIncorrect(formFeedback);
}
```

- The way that you were creating feedback was correct, I suspect that you were just getting mixed up with your arrays and indexes. This is why I tried to simplify your code and eliminate repeated sections.
- I combined the shuffling process with the creation of the multiple choice question. This is because the shuffled array that is passed into `item.setChoices` has to be built of `item.createChoice` objects. This can't be done in another scope because `item` is not available.
- Combining the logic for shuffling this way means that you don't need to have the letter prefixes in your questions `A)`. You also don't need the column that has the correct answer, because the process knows that the first answer is the correct one. So your sheet can be simplified to this:

  [image]
- For this script to work, the data needs to be organized in this way. (Though you can adapt it anyway you like of course)

#### References

- [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)
- [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)
- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)