# Google quiz form automation of generating makeup quiz

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Firstly, I'm a complete newbie for the Google apps script.

I want GAS to automatically create the makeup exam, which consists only of the questions that are answered wrong, but I'm not sure how I can do it at all. I want to use it in my part-time-job at cram school.

I think(from the newbie's perspective) I can use create() to generate the form and copy the items from the old quiz form if the question is answered wrong, but I'm not sure and don't know where to start learning.

I've borrowed a book of GAS from the library and searched a little bit(about conditional questioning of Google quiz form), so that I can code it myself, and I want someone to give me a tip of how to realize this kind of quiz form, or give me a simple sample code because I'm at a loss now. I don't want to read through this insanely thick book just to make one form.

Someone with experience in GAS, please help me. I need your help.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue of your script and your goal from `I think(from the newbie's perspective) I can use create() to generate the form and copy the items from the old quiz form if the question is answered wrong, but I'm not sure and don't know where to start learning.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65764842/creating-a-google-form-quiz-from-a-google-spreadsheet you can start here

Comment: Of course!
Thank you for the response!
I'm not a native speaker, so sometimes my English is not good enough. 

I want the quiz form to automatically create a new form if the answerer missed some questions, and I want the new form to include all the missed problems and don't want the new form to include the rest of the problems(The questions answered correctly). 

And I thought I could use the create method and if statement(I’m not sure), I don’t care how it is done. All I want to do is to streamline student’s testing and reviewing with the form quiz. Do these sentences make sense?

Comment: It's makes perfect sense. The idea is great and obvious. I surprised that Google Forms has no native tool for this. Basically there should be two steps: (1) make a quiz from a spreadsheet, (2) make a new spreadsheet from correct responses (another spreadsheet) of the quiz. The **Step 1** has at least two ready solutions (see my link, and google the Add-on 'Form Builder from Spreadsheet'). I didn't manage to find the ready solution for **Step 2**. Probably it's need to create from the scratch. It's interesting task, but you need to try the **Step 1** first, and then we'll see where to go.